# В какой таблице Bitrix хранится привязка полей ко вкладкам в редакторе?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

В админке есть поля и вкладки:Элемент, Ym, Анонс итд...
мне нужно сделать импорт этих полей с учетом привязки к вкладкам. никак не могу найти в какой таблице эта привязка сохраняется. Прошу помочь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: вот здесь они тоже видны]

Comment: При импорте штатные поля выгрузятся как надо. Что такое ИМ непонятно. По-умолчанию такого нет поэтому вряд-ли штатный импорт его захватит, так как эта вкладка добавлена скорее всего сторонним модулем.

Comment: это вкладка добавленная вручную и поля в ней тоже добавлены вручную, но они же гдето хранятся! вопрос где)). Точнее сами поля хранятся в таблице b_iblock_property, но мне не удается понять как система понимает что их надо показать на вкладке YM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройки форм редактирования хранятся в виде сериализованного массива в таблице `b_user_option`.

Как с этим работать через PHP рассматривается в документации:

1. https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5258

В блогах битрикса когда-то рассматривались вопросы как создавать такие записи через PHP:

1. https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/16182/blog/8524/
2. https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/11948/blog/7356/

Десериализация этого поля в админке реализована через js-обработчик, как и собственно сериализация для сохранения настроек. Так что проблем с обработкой по идее не должно возникать.

Comment: что именно там искать? выбрал определенного пользователя, у него 165 полей с непонятными названиями.. по каким CATEGORY и NAME сделать фильтрацию?

Comment: большое спасибо, рабобрался))) только вот как с этим дальше жить )))

Comment: @Monitorkin прощу всего просто экспортировать весь инфоблок, а потом на стороне на которой импорт будет делаться настроить форму руками. Так как на стороне куда импорт будут другие идентификаторы свойств и инфоблоков.

Comment: да, пришел к такому же выводу, что руками проще... хотя речь идет о 500 свойствах...

Comment: Ну тут разве что свой импорт писать, который будет это учитывать. Либо смотреть в сторону готового на маркетпэйсе.